# AWS Sagemaker: Is there a way to look at at the coefficients of the regressors of a 'linear learner - binary_classifier' model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm interested in getting a little more information on the model that's being built. Namely, what are the coefficients of the regressors that it is using for the prediction?

The loss function is automatically set to 'logistic'. I am assuming this means it is building a typical logistic regression model.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to directly read the model coefficients in Sagemaker.

I was able to read the ".params" file in mxnet. Here's what I did:

1. Launch an ec2 instance with mxnet AMI (there are multiple AMIs you can use, I used MXNet 1 Python 2.7 CPU Production)
2. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790953/logistic-regression-in-sagemaker/51792439) shows you how to extract the coefficients and intercept once you have read the file in MXNet.
   The **mod._arg_params** is a key-val pair, **fc0_weight** is your coefficient array and **fc0_bias** is the intercept for the model built.

Hope it helps!